TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options' None of the other posts helped me
I'm having problems with my code.
Error
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'"

Code
browser = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DIR, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)


That's not the entirety of your code. You are missing the definitions of all the parameters to .Chrome(). Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

You are using the .Chrome() constructor incorrectly. It's defined as
class Chrome(
    options: Options = None,
    service: Service = None,
    keep_alive: bool = True
)
Creates a new instance of the chrome driver. Starts the service and then creates new instance of chrome driver.

:Args:

options - this takes an instance of ChromeOptions
service - Service object for handling the browser driver if you need to pass extra details
keep_alive - Whether to configure ChromeRemoteConnection to use HTTP keep-alive.

According to the docs, the Chrome path should be passed in as part of options, not it's own parameter.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");

Without seeing all of your code, you'll have to fill in the gaps but your code should look more like
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(CHROME_DIR);
... # other options settings

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy() 
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
... # other capabilities settings

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

